# Function Definition: Printing a list of even integers

Tags: python, list, function, definition

I'm trying to define a function that returns a list of even integers from a list of overall integers

```
def print_even_numbers(n: list):
   '''Return a list of even numbers given a list of integers'''
   for x in list:
        if x % 2 == 0:
        return(x)
```

When I tried the code above, the error says that the type isn't iterable

Answer (score 2):

`list` is the name of the list type. So you cannot iterate over a type. you should use `n`. Second, your `return` is indented wrong. It should be on the top function level, because `return` exits the function. Then you need to collect the result somewhere.

```
def print_even_numbers(n):
    '''Return a list of even numbers given a list of integers'''
    result = []
    for x in n:
        if x % 2 == 0:
           result.append(x)
    return result
```

This can be written in short by a list comprehension:

```
def print_even_numbers(n):
    '''Return a list of even numbers given a list of integers'''
    return [x for x in n if x % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: How are these two different?

def print_even_numbers(n):
    '''Return a list of even numbers given a list of integers'''
    for x in n:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            return x

vs. 

def print_even_numbers(n):
    '''Return a list of even numbers given a list of integers'''
    return [x for x in n if x % 2 == 0]

Comment: @Deer530: The two versions do the same, but the second one is shorter.

Comment: When I tried the shortened version, it gave me a list of all the even integers with brackets around them (what I wanted), but for the first version, it only gave me back the first even number of the list.

Comment: Did you indent the function *exactly* as the example shows? What indentation level the `return` statement is at is *very* important so as to not end the loop before it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

- Wrong python syntax:

  ```
  def print_even_numbers(n: list):
  ```
- You don't need brackets:

  ```
  return(x)
  ```
- Wrong indentation. And wrong condition. (And don't use reserved python words such a `list` for your own variables.

  ```
  for x in list:
  ```

Summarize:

```
def print_even_numbers(n):
    '''Return a list of even numbers given a list of integers'''
    result = []
    for x in n:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            result.append(x)
    return result

print print_even_numbers(range(10))
>>> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

And finally more pythonic way is to use `yield` to implement desired behaviour:

```
def gen_even_numbers(n):
    for x in n:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            yield x

print list(gen_even_numbers(range(10)))
>>> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I tried this code, but when I gave it a list (e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4]), it only gives me back the first even integer. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `filter` built-in

```
def print_even_numbers(lst):
    return list(filter(lambda x: not x%2, lst))
```

Note: on python 2 `filter` returns a list already so there is no need to convert it

```
def print_even_numbers(lst):
    return filter(lambda x: not x%2, lst)
```

By the way, the function is named `print_even_numbers` but it does not print anything ;)